# MS Excel 2016 won't open CSV file without .csv extension

Tags: excel, macos, csv, excel-2016

I recently upgraded to MS Excel 2016 and was trying to open some old CSV files that lack the .csv extension.  The 2011 version of Excel and the recent Windows version of excel BOTH can open these files.  However, I have found no combination within the 2016 mac version of this program to open these files.  Is there a setting within 2016 Mac excel I am missing?

Comment: Not too familiar with Mac but surely you could rename them or copy to a new name.

Comment: Agreed but it seems crazy that MS took this functionality out of excel.